# How to dectect whether any blocks in a volume has a particular Minecraft ID?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wrote a command-block flying base (using this approach

) and it works (in Minecraft 1.15.2 vanilla). The main problem is that it will happily plow through and obliterate any obstacle. I want to put in proximity detection as a safeguard.

If I use the following inside a command block:

```
execute if block ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:air run clone ~7 ~ ~-5 ~-3 ~10 ~6 ~-9 ~ ~-5 replace move
```

It will move the 11x11x11 volume that contains it 6 blocks westward as long as there is a block of empty space behind it. The problem is that it only detects empty space directly behind it and only to a depth of 1 block.

How do I insure that all blocks that would be occupied by the structure in its new location are air prior to cloning it to that location without resorting to a huge chained command like...

```
execute if block ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:air if block ~-2 ~ ~ minecraft:air if block ~-3 ~ ~ minecraft:air if block ~-4 ~ ~ minecraft:air... etc. ... run clone ~7 ~ ~-5 ~-3 ~10 ~6 ~-9 ~ ~-5 replace move
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/execute if blocks`: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#Condition_subcommands. That compares two areas, so you can have a prepared area that's guaranteed to be only air and compare to that.

```
/execute if blocks <x> <y> <z> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block_x> <block_y> <block_z> all run clone ~7 ~ ~-5 ~-3 ~10 ~6 ~-9 ~ ~-5 replace move
```

This command executes if the area from x,y,z to x2,y2,z2 is the same as the area at block_x,block_y,block_z, with the same size as the first area.

Comment: Please check first what the command actually does before you answer. `/execute if blocks` compares two areas, not one area and a single block. The wiki also says that. I edited the answer accordingly, since I was just about to write an answer with the same command anyway, it just works differently than you think.

Comment: Hmm, that would explain why some of my experiments didn't work. Thanks for the correction!